# pyQT4 py3 Can't display image in QFrame background

Tags: python, image, background, widget, pyqt

I am trying since a little while to simply display an image in background of a QFrame and simply can't. I can see loads of example on the net but none of them seems to work with my code, and I can't understand why :

```
import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QBrush, QPixmap

class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #central widget
        self.theboard = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.theboard)
        self.resize(360, 760)
        self.setWindowTitle('Name')
        self.show()

class Board(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initBoard()

    def initBoard(self):
        print("ddd")
        frame = Board
        palette = QPalette(self)
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("ImageTest.jpg")))
        frame.setPalette(palette)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWin()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

will return:

```
TypeError: QWidget.setPalette(QPalette): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'
```

If I don't pass my QFrame in a variable and do as such :

```
palette = QPalette(self)
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("ImageTest.jpg")))
self.setPalette(palette)
```

No more errors but my background is still blank. Same thing if I just try to fill a color instead of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a top-level widget, you need to set the [autoFillBackground](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property to get this to work:

```
    def initBoard(self):
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = QPalette(self)
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(QPixmap("ImageTest.jpg")))
        self.setPalette(palette)
```

Alternatively, and more simply, use a [style-sheet](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html) to set the background image:

```
    def initBoard(self):
        self.setStyleSheet('background-image: url("ImageTest.jpg")')
```

Comment: That's wonderful thank you so much for your answer, all good now.